# What is the best way to refactor this code?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

What's a more effective way of writing the following code:

```
<button onclick="changeRed()">red</button>
<button onclick="changeGray()">gray</button>
<button onclick="changeBlack()">black</button>    

myLoader = document.getElementsByClassName('preloader');
    function changeGray() {
        for (i = 0; i < myLoader.length; i++) {         
            myLoader[i].setAttribute("id", "gray");
        } 
    }

    function changeBlack() {
        for (i = 0; i < myLoader.length; i++) {
            myLoader[i].setAttribute("id", "black");
        }
    }

    function changeRed() {
        for (i = 0; i < myLoader.length; i++) {
            myLoader[i].setAttribute("id", "red");
        }
    }
```

I am using a for loop as a workaround for using multiple ID's on a single page (this is for a specific mockup - will not be used in production)

I am looking for a way to write this without using multiple change___() functions.

Comment: Why not create only one function `changeColor(color)` that receives the `color` as an argument?

Comment: Why would you be setting an id? ids are singular, so if you are setting it to more than one element that is not the best practice. If it is just one element, there are better ways to set it, but still makes little sense on changing the id.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the color as an argument to the function:

```js
    function changeColor(color) {
        for (i = 0; i < myLoader.length; i++) {
            myLoader[i].setAttribute("id", color);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor so that u accept a color value on the function, and keep only one function to set the value

```
<button onclick="setColor('red')">red</button>
<button onclick="setColor('gray')">gray</button>
<button onclick="setColor('black')">black</button>    


myLoader = document.getElementsByClassName('preloader');
    function setColor(color) {
        for (i = 0; i < myLoader.length; i++) {         
            myLoader[i].setAttribute("id", color);
            myLoader[i].setAttribute("style", 'color:'+color);
        } 
    }
```